# Error establishing database connection if i dont type https before domain

Tags: wordpress

Site worked properly till recently when i got EEDBC error. Accidentaly realised that i can get to ebsite only if I type https before domain. What could be the problem? (And solution, of course)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay close attention to whether the URLs that you found have `www.` included. If your database includes a URL without it or vice versa, then this needs to be changed to match your database.
Check the `wp-config.php` file in your directory and change it. Without seeing the config file I could not answer the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

The prolem was, that my hosting provider moved directory from subdirectory to root folder on their own without notice